# strip text to create list and compare 2 similar lists

Tags: python, text, strip

I need to split text out of file names which look like this: `'foo_bar_1_10.asc.gz'` and I have a corresponding text list for each one of these files that looks like this: `'1  10'`.  This corresponding list is what I want to re-create.  The reason is I need to compare all of my files to a master list to find missing files.  So ultimately  I need a method to compare the two lists (diff?)  Any help would be great

```
import os
newtxt = []
oldtxt = '\foobar\master_list.txt'
wd = '\foobar'


for file in os.listdir(wd):
    file = file.split('.')
    subpieces = file[0].split('_')
    numbers = ' '.join(subpieces[-2:])
    newtxt.append(numbers)
    print txt
```

@@@ Update @@@
I now I have 2 lists with line numbers (using a function similar to nl in unix -- named `nl` and output looks something like this `1: 1  10` and `2: 1  12`.  I need to check for missing values in `newtxt` from `oldtxt`.  I've tried this:

```
s = set(nl(newtxt))
diff = [x for x in nl(oldtxt) if x not in s]
print diff
```

What this returns is some text characters and not what I expected.  Any help?

Comment: Also, the filename would be 1_10.asc.gz, and you want it stripped down to '1 10' and thrown into newtxt? Just to verify that that is inded what you want

Comment: @Tadgh you are correct.  That is what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're struggling with the string parsing part. First split up the file name into pieces by calling the string `.split` method, splitting by a period:

```
>>> file = 'foo_bar_1_10.asc.gz'
>>> pieces = file.split('.')
>>> pieces
['foo_bar_1_10', 'asc', 'gz']
```

Then split that up into subpieces based on the _ character:

```
>>> subpieces = pieces[0].split('_')
>>> subpieces
['foo', 'bar', '1', '10']
```

You can then join the last two pieces back together, separated by a space, like this:

```
>>> numbers = ' '.join(subpieces[-2:])
>>> numbers
'1 10'
```

Comment: thanks for getting me up and going.  I can now create the lists I want.  I've updated the question, can you provide advice about the diff?

Comment: @KennyC that you should really be a separate question, but you might want to look at [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments (and a path to a solution that you'll feel great to have figured out by yourself):

- Make sure you escape the `\` in `\foobar`, as `\f` won't give you what you expect
- The `.replace` method uses **2** arguments: what you to replace, what you to replace it with. You miss one.
- If you know how to replace `foo_bar_`, by, say, '', you can do the same thing with the extension, and replacing a `_` by, say, a `' '`...

Answer (score 0):

I guess [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) would be easiest. As you want to maintain spaces replace every non-numeric character with a space and then strip the leading and trailing spaces away

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'foo_bar_1_10.asc.gz'
>>> re.sub('[^\d]',' ',a).strip()
'1 10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say

> s = '1_10.asc.gz'

Then

> l = s.split('.')[0].split('_')
>   #Note l = ['1','10']

If you need '1 10', then do

> item = ' '.join(l)

To do a 'diff', use set difference (usage depends on what version of python you run). See 
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set
or if python2.4 and below:
http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Comment: I've updated my question to include the set difference.  Can you provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Heres another solution using regex to parse through all the files in the list.

```
import os
import re
reg1 = re.compile("\d+_\d+")
newtxt = []
wd = '\foobar'
for file in os.listdir(wd)
    match = reg1.search(file)
    if match:
        newtxt.append(match.group().replace('_', ' '))      
        print file
    else:
        print("no match found")
```